# How functional is Deckard's apartment in "Blade Runner"?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner, props, setting, worldbuilding

After about a thousand viewings of "Blade Runner," combined with material like [this](http://s233.photobucket.com/user/it4edda/media/Deckardapt2-1.jpg.html), [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-02wvSr41n4s/TqMMLnZsm3I/AAAAAAAAMy8/hmzBnRL9S20/s1600/BladeRunner_046Pyxurz.jpg), and [this](https://youtu.be/vo1k0tgOSHI), I'm still struggling to make sense of some of the things I think I see in Deckard's apartment. Specifically:

1. What are the countertop appliances in the kitchen? I'm pretty sure I see a coffee maker; is the cylindrical thing a rice cooker? a hot water dispenser?
2. Are the bath and toilet separated? That's not standard American practice.
3. I think I see a deep, Japanese-style tub in the bathroom (e.g., in the video above). Is that right?
4. Several of the speculative floor plans I found (see above) have the tub angled at 45 deg. to the wall. Can that possibly be?

(There's also the question of how an ex-cop with no apparent income can afford that apartment, but I'm guessing that we just need to suspend disbelief there and enjoy the movie.)

Comment: He's not an ex-cop, he's a [futuristic robot who was on loan to the police from the Tyrell Corporation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1386/20774). Presumably his lifestyle is funded by the corporation who provided him to the police service. Sorry. Spoilers.

Comment: Help me out. I know he's a replicant (origami unicorn, etc.), but how do you know he's on loan from Tyrell? Or is that an inference from the ban on replicants?

Comment: What's wrong with having the tub at an angle? Presumably the dead spaces alongside are used for plumbing and storage.

Comment: @Richard Have you ever seen that in real life? (Or, more specifically, have you ever seen it in the home of someone who isn't ostentatiously wasting space?)

Comment: Yes, my old bath was a jacuzzi. It wasn't flush to the wall and had a sort of carpeted step between the bath and the wall that concealed the water pump and the controls.

Comment: Huh. OK. I guess that's plausible.

Comment: I assumed he was on loan because his police colleague **knows that he's a replicant** and yet hasn't plugged him full of lead.

Comment: Regarding #2, it may not be standard practice where you've been, but there are places in the US where it is. Just about every new-build house in Florida I viewed had the toilet in a separate room from the tub, a smaller room inside the bathroom.

Comment: The world the film takes place in, and the cultural mergers that seem to have taken place don't have much to do with "America" anymore, it seems?